# swift navigation bar settings inside a function

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to process a navigation inside a reusble func i cannot get it to work this is the code i have so far.

```
static func navigationBarShow()  {

        let navigationCoontroller = UINavigationController()
        navigationCoontroller.navigationBarHidden = false

        navigationCoontroller.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.4, green:0.76, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0)
        navigationCoontroller.navigationBar.translucent = false
        navigationCoontroller.title = "Signup"

        navigationCoontroller.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        navigationCoontroller.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing it as an extension to `UINavigationController` and use `self` as the navigation controller. You are creating a new `UINavigationController` instance each time you want to display a navigation bar and that instance is never being displayed on the screen.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func showNavigationBar() {

        self.navigationBarHidden = false

        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.4, green:0.76, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0)
        self.navigationBar.translucent = false
        self.title = "Signup"

        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]


    }

}
```

Then, from any `UINavigationController`, you can call `showNavigationBar()`.

### Update:

In the code for any subclass of `UIViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, call `navigationController!.showNavigationBar()`.

For example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.navigationController!.showNavigationBar()
    }

}
```

Note that the `!` assumes your view controller is embedded in a navigation controller. If any vc is not embedded in a navigation controller but you want a navigation bar, you should consider embedding it in a navigation controller.

Comment: You beat me to it, by **seconds**! (Voted)

Comment: @Matthew I have a helper file where I store all of my func, I use the same nav info in all of my views. I wanted to avoid having the same code in all of the views. If i put that extension in another file how can i call it in the different views. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
    let navigationCoontroller = UINavigationController()
```

creates a brand-new navigation controller every time you run it.

Unless the code you posted is run once and only once, that's wrong, since every time you call that function you create a new navigation controller